# How to diagnose Run-time error 429?

Tags: windows-xp, debug, runtime-error

We have a computer at work that has a software that stopped working after a security update was remotely ran to the domain server / database. When opening the program it gives Run-time error 429 -  ActiveX component can't create object. The program is the first one to be launched when you start any one of the CRM/Billing/etc programs from the package, and acts as the database selector. I know this program has a infoscreen that has embedded IE control to display ads from the manufacturer (Visma) and has some database connectivity. I think the database update changed something.

I've been trying to diagnose the error with various programs to determine the cause. I thought I know this much about fault finding to be able to determine the cause, but it's beyond just opening the program with dependency walker to find what dll's are missing.

How and what program should I use to find out what is failing with the program? This question is rather not to fix the issue, but more about learning how to fix these kind of issues in the future.

Edit1: Oh yeah, the computer is running Windows XP SP3.

Comment: It just might help if you actually tells us which program you are talking about...

Comment: The program is Visma Nova, but I don't think knowing this will help anything.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the custom DLL/OCX  for the programs has been erased from your system during the security update. Hence you can try performing a system restore to an earlier date and see if that resolves this issue.  You can follow the below Microsoft article for performing system restore,

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306084

Comment: He did mention running Dependency Walker to find out which DLLs were missing.

Comment: DLL's listed missing from the computer were ieshims.dll and wer.dll, but they're delay load and should not matter. After those the dependency walker lists ncrypt.dll missing also (again delay load). Nothing has changed on the local computer and no updated were ran, so it feels like the program uses a call thats not in one of the dll's it had. Or something.